# plpgsql in EDB: SPL procedure with SPL-style OUT parameter or a function cannot be invoked using CALL in PL/pgSQL

Tags: enterprisedb

I'm trying to run natively correct plpgsql code in EDB environment. Unfortunately there is a problem. Interestingly, the first run does not generate an error. Restarts generate an error, but after a few repetitions, there is no error again.
In PosgreSQL, the syntax DOES NOT CAUSE any problems.
Below is an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1()
AS $procedure$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    null;
END;
$procedure$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test2()
AS $procedure$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    call test1();
END;
$procedure$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
;



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test3()
AS $procedure$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    call test2();
END;
$procedure$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```

And now try to run it in postgresql way and EDB way:

```
--run it few times as edb - error occurs randomly
begin
    test3();
end;

--once again as plpgs - no error occurs but... check last call
do
$$
begin
    CALL test3();
end;
$$


--once again as plpgs with exception block. - now error occurs same as edb call
do
$$
declare
v_sqlstate text;
v_message text;
v_context text;
begin
    CALL test3();
     EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS v_sqlstate = returned_sqlstate,v_message = message_text,v_context = pg_exception_context;
                RAISE NOTICE 'sqlstate: %,message: %,context: %', v_sqlstate,v_message,v_context;

end;
$$
```

Error is:

```
ERROR:  SPL procedure with SPL-style OUT parameter or a function cannot be invoked using CALL in PL/pgSQL
HINT:  You might want to use SELECT instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test3() line 4 at CALL
edb-spl function inline_code_block line 2 at procedure/function invocation statement
SQL state: 42809
```

What am I missing???

Answer (score 1):

I find that this might be a bug fixed in EPAS 13.8 (DB-1818).
https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/epas/13/epas_rel_notes/epas13_8_12_rel_notes/

I guess you may try your test in this or later new minor version.

Best Regards.